# To express the idea of "it is you who ...", do you say in Italian "Sei tu che ..." instead of "È tu che ..."?

Tags: grammar

> **Sei tu che** non hai mai voluto prendere un impegno serio con me.

You use the constructions "it **is** you who ..." and "c'**est** toi qui ..." in English and French respectively with a third-person singular *be* verb. I wonder if in Italian the *be* verb in this expression always corresponds to the *who* in question? Is it incorrect to say:

> **È tu che** non hai mai voluto prendere un impegno serio con me.

Comment: Yes, it is incorrect.

Comment: It's incorrect because in Italian the subject is "tu" and not "it" or "ce".

Comment: Actually I am almost tempted now to ask in English.SE *why* English adds the spurious subject *it* to the sentence. It doesn't seem to make any sense...

Comment: @DenisNardin - its called expletive subject: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/5758/what-does-it-refer-to-in-its-raining

Comment: @DaG In Italian, is it more like "**you're the one who ...**"? Can you also say "Sei tu **quello che** non hai ..."? I'm not sure why the subject "tu" and the verb "sei" need to be inverted here.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, **È tu che non hai...* is incorrect.

Each language has its own quirks, so do not try to find too precise parallels between two of them. Even two Romance languages, such as Italian and French, may differ in subtle ways, as in this case or, say, in

*Si vedono le cose*

versus

*On voit les choses*

(where Italian requires a plural verb, agreeing with the plural *cose*, while French uses a singular one). And many more cases.

Back to our sentence: decomposing it, you have a verb (*sei*) agreeing with it subject (*tu*), all followed by a relative clause introduced by *che*, whose verb agrees with its own subject (*che*) and so in the second person, since *che* refers to *tu*.

The case of *Sei tu quello che...* is different. It is a correct beginning for an Italian phrase, but has a different syntactical structure. The subject is again *tu* and the verb is again *sei*, but now they are followed by a predicate noun, or phrase. Simplify it by considering sentences like *Sei tu il vincitore* or *Sei tu il mio migliore amico*: those are simply emphatic ways to say *Tu sei il vincitore* etc.

Now, in your example, the predicative part is a whole phrase: *quello che non ha mai voluto...* Notice that the verb is in the third person here, since it agrees with the pronoun *quello* (or, more precisely, it agrees with the pronoun *che* that refers to *quello*). You could also say *Sei tu la persona che non ha...* and so on.

In this case, you might change the order of the words: *Tu sei quello che non ha mai...*: it would be a grammatical sentence. However, since you are apparently rebuking someone, the emphasis given by putting *tu* after the verb, and so stressing it (probably implying “it was not me, not anyone else, but you”), is quite appropriate.

On the other hand, *Tu sei che non hai mai voluto...* sounds quite unusual, hardly intelligible, and won't be found except, perhaps, as a poetic licence.

Comment: Hi. How do you translate the phrase "Sei tu che ..." in my question into English?

Comment: You should ask that to an English-speaking person, but I'd say, exactly as you did, “It's you who...”.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm that *È tu che...* is incorrect, the only corect form is *Sei tu che*. The locution is the same as English, but its form is different. In Italian, the subject is the same as the dependent clause.